# Mistake in excercise with differentiation

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I have an excercise given where $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and we have that $x(t):=\int_0^t exp(a(t-s))f(s)ds$. Now we are supposed to show that $x$ solves the differential equation $d_t(x(t))= ax(t)+f(t)$.

I would say that this is impossible, as the fact that $f$ is just a bounded function does not mean, that there is any meaning in the integral expression as this integral does not exist (in general) for functions that are just bounded and I would say that if you would for example look at Dirichlet's function, than this theorem would probably not hold, but I wanted to get your confirmation about this, before complaining about this. (Maybe there is anybody here who knows what we need to demand for f(probably continuous is sufficient, but maybe the fact that the integral exists is sufficient).

Comment: Right, you need some regularity for the integral to exist. And you need some regularity for $x$ to be differentiable. What regularity assumptions you need depends on whether the differential equation is to be understood in the classical sense, almost everywhere, in the sense of distributions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, let's make some hypotheses about $f$ so that we know that the integral makes sense. In particular, let's assume that $f$ is continuous. The issue is to differentiate correctly the integral $$\int_0^t g(t,s)\,ds\,,$$
assuming, for example, that $g$ and $\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial t}$ are continuous.
(Otherwise, the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus will be hopeless, as will — without some care — the hypothesis for differentiating under the integral sign.)